# netdata metrics displayed in Grafana shows incorrect values

Tags: grafana, graphite, netdata

I'm trying to get netdata metrics to Graphite and use Grafana for plotting historical metrics.

However the unit of the metrics doesn't work well with Grafana. When plotting CPU utilization percentage I get values like 1000000000% and 6000000000% with Unit set as Percent(0-100).

I'm I missing something?

The architecture looks like below

NetData ---> Graphite ----> Grafana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the values returned to Grafana are not percent but datasize probably in bits.If you want to display percent, you have to use some functions like this :

```
asPercent(<your metric>, <maximum of this metrics>, 0)
```

More details on function of graphite : https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html